# hector_slam + rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, hokuyo-node, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use hector_mapping with the hokuyo_node. the connection between hokuyo_node and the lidar is ok and it seems like /scan send data to the node /hector_slam is also ok.

But I can realize a realtime map construction with rviz? Do I need to record in a bag file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37465/hector_slam-+-rviz/) by [sjigi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2732/sjigi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-28**:
yes you can, check out  http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

**Comment by [sjigi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2732/sjigi123/) on 2012-06-28**:
But I got nothing with the map. Do I need to configure something ?

**Comment by [sjigi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2732/sjigi123/) on 2012-06-29**:
I can't clearly understand how to set up a launch file with the base_frame or odom. I get the same error /map doesnt exist.

My purpose is to use the hector_slam (ie hector_mapping) in order to do for the time being the same process as we can see on the video in the hector_slam wiki page. I am only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when using gmapping , gmapping connects the /map frame to /odom frame then you begin to visualize the map in rviz and I suppose that you may use hector_slam for this because hector_slam uses hector_mapping. check out http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0